# System is not started due to Mysq server issue

Tags: 18.04, mysql

My system is recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.
The system is not started. I am connected with the recovery mode.
When I tried to empty spaces,
I am facing the issue below:
[image]

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.   *Ubuntu's packages.ubuntu.com has already dropped 18.04 support making it harder to help 18.04 users*

Comment: try `touch /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` before doing the autoremove.